# Copying part of QTableView

Tags: qt, uitableview, copy

So I have a question very closely related to another question I've seen on here but when I tried posing my question there I got no responses, I'm hoping by asking this as a fresh question someone can help me out. Basically I want simply copy a portion of my table that I've created so that I can paste it to an excel file. Here's what I have:

```
    QAbstractItemModel *abmodel = ui.tableview->model();
    QItemSelectionModel *model = ui.tableview->selectionModel();
    QModelIndexList list = model->selectionIndexes();
    qSort(list);
    QModelIndex index = list.first();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    QModelIndex index = list.at(i);
    QString text = abmodel->data(index).toString();
    copy_table.append(text);

    if(index.row() != previous.row())
    {
        copy_table.append('\n');
    }
    else
    {
        copy_table.append('\t');
    }
    previous = index;
}

QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
clipboard->setText(copy_table);
```

This will copy a column fine, but when I attempt to copy a row or say a 2x2 subtable the row index gets messed up, incorrectly assigning the row index for the values. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, already figured it out, sorry anyone that wasted their time and looked.

```
void TestCopyTable::on_pushButton_copy_clicked()
{
QAbstractItemModel *abmodel = ui.tableView->model();
QItemSelectionModel * model = ui.tableView->selectionModel();
QModelIndexList list = model->selectedIndexes();

qSort(list);

if(list.size() < 1)
    return;

QString copy_table;
QModelIndex last = list.last();
QModelIndex previous = list.first();

list.removeFirst();

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    QVariant data = abmodel->data(previous);
    QString text = data.toString();

    QModelIndex index = list.at(i);
    copy_table.append(text);

    if(index.row() != previous.row())

    {
        copy_table.append('\n');
    }
    else
    {
        copy_table.append('\t');
    }
    previous = index;
}

copy_table.append(abmodel->data(list.last()).toString());
copy_table.append('\n');

QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
clipboard->setText(copy_table);
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I wrote some code based on Phil's to copy the selection when the user types Control-C.

I subclassed `QTableWidget` and overrode `keyPressEvent()`:

```
void MyTableWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {
    // If Ctrl-C typed
    // Or use event->matches(QKeySequence::Copy)
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_C && (event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier))
    {
        QModelIndexList cells = selectedIndexes();
        qSort(cells); // Necessary, otherwise they are in column order

        QString text;
        int currentRow = 0; // To determine when to insert newlines
        foreach (const QModelIndex& cell, cells) {
            if (text.length() == 0) {
                // First item
            } else if (cell.row() != currentRow) {
                // New row
                text += '\n';
            } else {
                // Next cell
                text += '\t';
            }
            currentRow = cell.row();
            text += cell.data().toString();
        }

        QApplication::clipboard()->setText(text);
    }
}
```

Output example (tab-separated):

```
foo bar baz qux
bar baz qux foo
baz qux foo bar
qux foo bar baz
```

Comment: A fine, ready to use code snippet. +1 especially for the qSort of the cells. That would have tripped me up for a while

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230222/selected-rows-line-in-qtableview-copy-to-qclipboard : you can use event->matches(QKeySequence::Copy) instead of manually checking for ctrl + c

Comment: Ah that sounds better

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the cdline:
  qSort(cells); // Necessary, otherwise they are in column order
currently(20190118) it brings a warning:
Warnung: 'qSort >' is deprecated: Use std::sort

so my solution to replace the line with:
  std::sort(cells.begin(),cells.end());
Compile, Run OK -> so far so good. But Question: Benefit of this cdline?
I found there is no one. Made several Test with copy from gui and parsing it to excel. Everything was fine even with the scenario 2x2 or othe XxY.