# Paste in the field of QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, paste, qtableview

I need to implement a function in python which handles the "paste" when "ctrl+v" is pressed. I have a `QTableView`, i need to copy a field of the table and paste it to another field of the table. I have tried the following code, but the problem is that i don't know how to read the copied item (from the clipboard) in the tableView. (As it already copies the field and i can paste it anywhere else like a notepad). Here is part of the code which I have tried:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
def __init__(self,md,parent=None):
  QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
   # initially construct the visible table
  self.tv=QTableView()
  self.tv.show()

  # set the shortcut ctrl+v for paste
  QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+v'),self).activated.connect(self._handlePaste)

  self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
  self.layout.addWidget(self.tv)

# paste the value  
def _handlePaste(self):
    if self.tv.copiedItem.isEmpty():
        return
    stream = QDataStream(self.tv.copiedItem, QIODevice.ReadOnly)
    self.tv.readItemFromStream(stream, self.pasteOffset)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can obtain the clipboard form the `QApplication` instance of your app using `QApplication.clipboard()`, and from the `QClipboard` object returned you can get the text, image, mime data, etc. Here is an example:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui as gui

class Widget(gui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        gui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        # initially construct the visible table
        self.tv=gui.QTableWidget()
        self.tv.setRowCount(1)
        self.tv.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tv.show()

        # set the shortcut ctrl+v for paste
        gui.QShortcut(gui.QKeySequence('Ctrl+v'),self).activated.connect(self._handlePaste)

        self.layout = gui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tv)



    # paste the value  
    def _handlePaste(self):
        clipboard_text = gui.QApplication.instance().clipboard().text()
        item = gui.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText(clipboard_text)
        self.tv.setItem(0, 0, item)
        print clipboard_text



app = gui.QApplication([])

w = Widget()
w.show()

app.exec_()
```

Note: I've used a `QTableWidget` cause I don't have a model to use with `QTableView` but you can adapt the example to your needs.

Comment: AttributeError: 'QTableView' object has no attribute 'setItem'

Comment: Did you read the final note? I've used a `QTableWidget` not a `QTableView` also check the code ;)

Comment: @pbreach Some people forget to accept the answers ;) In any case you can ask the OP directly... maybe he/she has another reason :D