# Copy a Python PyQt QTreeView data from Python to Excel via copy/paste?

Tags: python, excel, treeview, pyqt

Is there a method of copying data from a PyQT QTreeView - or QTableView using the classical <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> mechanism, or do I need to write a explicit module to write a CSV file from the application data using something like xlrd?

The effect I see at the moment is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> takes only 1 item, not a bunch, even when I code selection modes to take multiple selections.

Comment: There's no builti in method - you'll have to write your own. No need for anything fancy, though. Just format the data as csv and put it on the clipboard. If you do a little web-searching, you'll probably find plenty of example code (e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3135737/984421), [this](http://retrofocus28.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/pyqt-qtablewidget-copy-and-past-excel.html),  etc, etc).