# Copying a Row in from table in qt in c++

Tags: c++, qt

I need to copy the row with each and every cell

For Example : if this were the data in my tableview and I select the rows and copied

name number1 data1

he output it gives is only the first column of the row "name" , I need to copy all the highlighted part of row i.e entire row ?How can we solve this

Following is the code Written:

```
void OTPWindow::initLogTable()
{
    QList<OtpLog> logs;
    int ret = otpRepo.fetchOtpLogs(logs);
    if( ret != errorCodes::SUCCESS )
    {
        //todo: error message
        QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Critical, QString("SafeOTP"),
            QString("OTPLogs could not be fetched"),QMessageBox::Ok, this);
        msgBox.exec();
        QLOG_ERROR() << "fetchLogs error " << ret;
        return;
    }

    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(0,5,this); //5 columns
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("Date")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Customer")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(QString("Server")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, new QStandardItem(QString("Authorized by")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, new QStandardItem(QString("Description")));

    for(QList<OtpLog>::Iterator lIt = logs.begin(); lIt != logs.end(); lIt++)
    {
        OtpLog& log = *lIt;
        QList<QStandardItem*> row;
        row.push_back(new QStandardItem(log.when.toString("dd MMM yyyy, hh:mm")));
        row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.customer)));
        row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.server)));
        row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.author)));
        row.push_back(new QStandardItem(QString(log.reason)));

        model->appendRow(row);
    }

    // set the data model
    ui->tblLog->setModel(model);
    ui->tblLog->setColumnHidden(1, true);
    ui->tblLog->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);

    // set the column widths
    int tw = ui->tblLog->width() - 5;
    int w = tw / 6;

    for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    {
        ui->tblLog->setColumnWidth(i,w);
        tw -= w;
    }
    ui->tblLog->setColumnWidth(4,tw);
}
```

Here tblLog is my tableview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selected Rows/Line in QTableView copy to QClipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230222/selected-rows-line-in-qtableview-copy-to-qclipboard)

Comment: I read that example and implemented but was not able to succeed .Is  there any other way

Comment: You probably have to use qitemselectionmodel